# Microsoft Azure SQL DataSync

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I’m currently having two problems with Azure SQL DataSync

1- I have a sync group to backup data from the hub to another database, it worked well but when I deleted records from the hub and synced it started throwing errors related to “BulkDeleteCommand” saying cannot insert the value NULL into column “local_create_peer_timestamp” and the error code is 3621.

2- I have another database that I use for development but it takes the hub’s data every 6 hours or so, when I tried to edit the data on this database I couldn’t, it throws the same error as the previous one.

Comment: The first question, you delete the data from  hub database, then sync the data and get the error. The second, you edit the data in member database and it also throws the error when sync from hub to member, am I right? did you delete one row or just one column?

Comment: @LeonYue correct! the first database stores some records and over time get rid of it so that don't sync back to the member database, the second database is in another sync group that I want to update its data but can also edit the data as I use it for development.

Comment: Can you please try stop the data sync before you delete the data?

Comment: @LeonYue the data deletion happens on a production environment automatically and I can’t tell when this will happen because whenever a user do something I get rid of some temporary data for that user so ideally the member database should reflect these changes, correct?

Comment: Is the error happening on the `provision_marker_dss` table?

Comment: @mauridb yes!! the table that logs everything I think.

Comment: Ok. Did you have already run this script: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSQLDataSyncHealthChecker ?